# Where does flash cookie store on Mac?

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

Where does flash cookie store on Mac? I searched this question in google. Some people say the flash cookie is a .sol file stored in folder /User’s Home Folder/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player/.
But I cannot find this file/folder on my mac. Where is it? Could someone kindly tell me how to find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

They're stored in `~/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player/#SharedObjects/<some random string>/`, and then you'll have subfolders for each domain name. For Google Chrome, the path is `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash/WritableRoot/#SharedObjects/<some random string>/` instead.

Note that on Mac OS X Lion, the Library folder is hidden, you need to open it using the "Go To" menu in Finder or via Terminal.

Comment: Yes. I find it via Terminal. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Mac OS X 10.7 and your whole library folder is hidden, see: http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20082044-263/os-x-lion-where-did-my-library-go/